# A bag contains 3 red, 4 blue, and 5 green balls.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Peter draws a ball from the bag, and then Angelina draws a ball. What is the probability that Angelina got a green ball?

So far I have this:
Scenario A: 1st ball is not green, 2nd green: 7/12 * 5/11 = 35/132
Scenario B: 1st ball is green, 2nd green: 5/12 * 4/11 = 20/132
--> $$\frac{55}{132} = \frac{5}{12}$$

Comment: @RobertZ please see my edit.

Comment: So the first ball is green or it is not green...

Comment: Yes, you are correct!

Comment: correction Wolf: : You have $$\frac{20 + 35}{132} = \frac{55}{132}= \frac 5{12}$$

Comment: $$P=P_1+P_2=\frac  {5}{11}\frac  {7}{12}+\frac  {4}{11}\frac  {5}{12}=\frac{5}{12 \times 11}(4+7)=\frac{5}{12 \times 11}(11)=\frac  {5}{12}$$

Comment: @Isham  Thanks for making my point, in yet a second manner.

Comment: lol yw @amWhy......

Comment: Glad to see your correction, based on feedback, @Wolf.  You're welcome.

Comment: thank you @amWhy

Comment: thank you @RobertZ

Comment: See this very similar question asked today! - https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2862111/571724

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Second marble is of same color](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2862111/second-marble-is-of-same-color)

Comment: In our time, they would use urn, now does it become bag ?

Comment: Does Peter put the ball back before Angeline makes her draw?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your approach is fine, but it's worth realizing that unless you know something about the ball Peter has chosen, he may as well not have chosen at all, in which case Angelina simply has a $5/12$ chance of choosing a green ball.

Where this point really becomes worth understanding is if, for example, not only Peter, but also Olivia, Ned, Melissa, and Larry choose balls before Angelina.  The tree of possibilities is tedious and messy, but the answer is still $5/12$.

Answer (score 8):

Angela's draw is actually independent from the order she draws the ball whether she is first, second, ..., or twelfth (surprisingly enough). So, the probability of her drawing a green ball is actually $\dfrac{5}{12}$. To give you a better explanation, suppose there are $k$ green balls and $n$ total balls. Then, the probability that Angela draws a green ball is:

$$\require{cancel} \dfrac{k}{n}\dfrac{k-1}{n-1}+\dfrac{n-k}{n}\dfrac{k}{n-1} = \dfrac{k(k-1)+k(n-k)}{n(n-1)} = \dfrac{k \cancel{(n-1)}}{n \cancel{(n-1)}} = \dfrac{k}{n}$$

Which is the same probability that Peter has for drawing a green ball.

Comment: "Angela's draw is actually independent from Peter's draw" - it's not. You're probably misusing the word "independent". The probability distribution for Angelina's draw is the same as it would be if Peter did not draw, but that's not what "independent" means. If they were independent, we would have equalities like P(Angelina draws red AND Peter draws red) = P(Angelina draws red)*P(Peter draws red).

Comment: @user2357112 I corrected my wording. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Brute force: condition on the color of the first drawn ball, there are 3 cases. Find the probability of each case happening, and what is the resulting probability in each case.

Then group them together in one final expression.